# How to I supply models in specific order for Sequalize?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

As of time of writing, I'm having trouble understanding how my tables are currently loaded into Sequalize instance and how to alter the load order. Asking inorder to get rid of an error `EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: User_Events is not associated to Events!`. User_Events including a child foreign of Events table and a child foreign key of User table.

Currently I have created a sequalize.js file, which initialized Sequalize and I am passing sequalize.js to each of my 4 models separately. Each of my query imports those models and main file: server.js invokes sequalize.sync(), which properly creates all my tables with relevant foreign keys.

When I console.log(sequalize) in server.js and check models, I get following array:

```
models: {
    User_Events: User_Events,
    Invitees: Invitees,
    User: User,
    Events: Events
  },
  modelManager: ModelManager {
    models: [ User_Events, Invitees, User, Events ],
    sequelize: [Circular *1]
  },
```

My first question is how does it determine how my models are currently loaded in and how can I ensure that I load my models so that all my associations function properly and do not run into EagerLoadingError.

Full application code for those, who might want to look a bit more in detail:  https://github.com/HasieEST/Mock-RSVP-backend